# Change button size (XAML)

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I'm trying to change the size of the button (XAML), making it larger (standard size: 20x12). When I put it higher, the button does not appear in full when I run the program:

[image]

```
<Button Name="generate"
            RelativePanel.Below="empty"
            RelativePanel.AlignHorizontalCenterWithPanel="True"
            Margin="0,45,0,0"
            x:Uid="GenerateButton"
            Content=""
            Click="generate_Click" 
            Width="40" Height="24"/>
```

Comment: Check the size of the parent element(s)

Comment: post the parent element xaml code

Comment: Assuming you're using the default font and font size for a UWP app, the default height for a button (Auto) is 32, so setting it to 24 (a smaller number) will cause that problem!

Answer (score 0):

If you set the `Height` of the `Button` to 24 you should also decrease the `Padding` to like 0 for the text to fit:

```
<Button Name="generate"
        RelativePanel.Below="empty"
        RelativePanel.AlignHorizontalCenterWithPanel="True"
        Margin="0,45,0,0"
        x:Uid="GenerateButton"
        Content=""
        Click="generate_Click" 
        Width="40" Height="24" Padding="0"/>
```

You may also want to set the `MinWidth` property to 40 rather than the `Width` property unless the text is very short.